# MVC 6 and ADFS authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, adfs

We have an existing application that is using ASP.Net MVC 6 and Entity Framework 6.   We have our own custom user and role tables that must be kept.   We would like to add the ability to integrate with ADFS and Azure AD.

The application currently uses forms authentication.  AD integration is currently handled by mapping a user in our table to an AD account.  Another site with windows authentication enabled authenticates the user if they choose to login with windows credentials rather than a username and password and returns them back to the main site with a custom token to log them in.

What is the best approach using current technologies to add support for ADFS and Azure AD?  I am not necessarily looking for how to implement the solution.  I am just interested in recommendations on which technologies best support our need for mixed authentication.

Should we try to switch to ASP.Net Identity with a custom provider so that we can use our existing table and then use IdentityServer4?   Or should we use OWIN WS-Fed libraries or some other approach.  Perhaps we need to write our own issuer for ADFS to use our internal users/roles tables as an option.

Comment: I recommend to rephrase your text. It is currently one long paragrah, making it very hard to read. You should make it easy for the readers to understand your problem - WHAT do you ask for, WHAT did you try and HOW is your setup?

Also please know that this is not a solution center so people here should not tell you how to fix your problem but you can get hints or help to solve it yourself :-)

Comment: Thans @DHS.  I separated it into multiple paragraphs and tried to make it more clear what I am looking for.  I have not yet tried any approaches.  I am looking for advice on the best technologies to use for our needs.